# how to trace errors and crashes in Ubuntu itself?

Tags: login-screen, crash, log

I'm new in Linux, My Ubuntu has started crashing for some days randomly and closing everything, going back to login screen!!

- Is this the same as when windows hangs and you kill a program? (but Ubuntu killing all of them)
- Mainly how do you trace errors and view crash reports of Ubuntu itself?
- How can I get a log of what went wrong and find the root?
- Is there a troubleshooting solution like windows?
- Is there any popular process or set of instructions to follow in such times?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is looking  at Ubuntu log files after each crash and examine that whether new logs are added or Not.

All major logs in Ubuntu are in `/var/log` path, for example:

`/var/log/auth.log` -  Authentication logs - including sudo/su activity

`/var/log/boot.log` - Logs of booting process

`/var/log/crond.log` - Logs for cron daemon

`/var/log/messages` - Typical dumping point for messages not regarding the system

`/var/log/user.log` - Logs of all userlevels

`/var/log/syslog` - Logs from Different softwares and is a "general log"

`/var/log/kern.log` - Information being logged from the kernel

Beside above logs, there is a Troubleshooting guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TroubleShootingGuide).

Also there are some tracers that may be helpful such as [apport-retrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/apport-retrace.1.html).

Comment: `/var/crash/` may contain useful information too